# How do I use the additional Silverlight Toolkit controls?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I've got VS2010 installed, I've downloaded the Windows Phone add-in and the Silverlight Toolkit from CodePlex, but I cannot work out for the life of me how to *actually use* the controls in a Windows Phone 7 application...

How do I add the controls into the toolbox, or link them so that the XAML doesn't give me errors all the time?  For instance, using the Viewbox - the controls aren't implemented, and the XAML does not compile.

Comment: Make sure you're using the Silverlight 3 (pre-April) toolkit. Also, you may run into the Authenticode bug, sorry. And not all controls will 'just work' - you may need to end up re-templating and styling them for the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably running into this bug:

http://www.manyniches.com/windows-phone/signed-assemblies-bug-in-the-windows-phone-tools-ctp-refresh/

The Silverlight toolkit wasn't working for me after the April Update.

Comment: Indeed this is most likely the issue - as it is possible to get most SL3 controls to work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a reference to the Silverlight Toolkit assembly in your project?

By the way, Jeff Wilcox has [a comprehensive overview](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/03/toolkit-and-the-windows-phone/) of the Silverlight Toolkit controls that work on Windows Phone.

Comment: No - But as you posted that answer, I found the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Toolkit\Apr10\Bin folder on my PC and have add ALL of the .dlls to my project and the code and I still don't have access to them.  Please explain more, in the manner that you'd give your mother the instructions. Thanks!

Comment: Would [this post by Brad Tutterow](http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/03/20/Using-the-WrapPanel-from-the-Silverlight-Toolkit-on-Windows-Phone-7.aspx) be clear enough? It targets version 3 of the Silverlight Toolkit, but I guess it's still relevant for version 4.

Comment: Not sure my post was very comprehensive. Unfortunately v4.0 toolkit won't work on the phone, since it is based on a derivative of Silverlight 3 for now.